# How to parse improperly escaped string in python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working with a largish (2 gig) json file that I need to parse into Python.

The problem is that some of the data is improperly escaped, which is giving me an error.

Here is my code

```
import json

data = []
with open('full.json') as f:
for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

which is giving me the following error

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 64 (char 63)
```

I printed out the file and found the line that is giving me trouble

```
{"page_viewed":"Truck Repair Form - \342\204\242"}
```

I know its the `\342\204\242` section that is holding me back, I just need to figure out how to properly escape the backslashes.

Comment: Those are probably character escapes encoding *octal* values; `\342` is U+00E2 or `â` for example.

Comment: Here it is with less detail taken out. "page_viewed":"Truck Repair Form - \342\204\242"

Comment: Is that perhaps `Truck Repair Form - ™` in UTF-8?

Comment: My solution in the other answer will work for you if you use `chr()` instead of `unichr()` in the `replace_with_codepoint` function.